# PayPal POST Not Working for Site

Tags: paypal

I know someone out there has an answer to this question, so thanks in advance for any insight into this issue.

We are trying to pull in revenue information for payment transactions via POST method in the thank you page URL.

We have a return URL setup to drive users to a thank you page on our site, and we also have our return URL page setup as POST. However, we are not able to see the payment info for our users in the thank you page URL or on the page. We've tried both POST and GET to no avail.

We have a silent post URL set-up, but that is going back to our CRM. Ultimately, we'd like to pull the revenue info into Google Analytics, but it looks like that info is not getting posted when we do a test.

To add another layer of complexity, we reached out to PayPal customer service last week and their tech team used their Sandbox and tested via our thank you page and everything worked perfectly on their end.

That leads me to believe that it may be something on our own site that's blocking the URL info, but I'm not certain.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!